# very long table

Tags: tables

I need to fix this code for a very long table because it does not allow the file to be compiled.

```
 \begin{center}

 \begin{longtable}{|*8|}
 \hline
{\bf text} & {\bf  Acceptor} & {\bf Hydrogen atom}& {\bf  Donor } & {\bf No. of Frames}& {\bf  Fraction } & {\bf Average Length}  & {\bf Average Angle}\\
 \hline
1&GLU 73@OE2       & ARG 63@HH12     &ARG 63@NH1    &38472       &0.3890            &2.7931     &163.2221 \\
2&GLU 73@OE1        &ARG 63@HH22     &ARG 63@NH2    &35928       &0.3633       &2.7983     &162.5048 \\
3&ILE 61@O          &ARG 63@HH11     &ARG 63@NH1    &14490       &0.1465       &2.8612     &158.4143 \\
4&GLU 73@OE1        &ARG 63@HH21     &ARG 63@NH2    &14175       &0.1433       &2.7989     &158.1555\\ 
5&GLU 73@OE2         &ARG 63@HE      &ARG 63@NE     &8830       &0.0893        &2.8070     &158.1456\\ 
6&GLU 73@OE2        &ARG 63@HH22     &ARG 63@NH2     &6240       &0.0631       &2.8255     &153.4609\\
7&GLU 73@OE2        &ARG 63@HH21     &ARG 63@NH2     &3949       &0.0399       &2.8370     &150.3891\\
8&GLU 73@OE1         & ARG 63@HE      &ARG 63@NE     &2677       &0.0271       &2.8550     &150.1653\\
9&GLU 73@OE1        &ARG 63@HH12     &ARG 63@NH1     &2539       &0.0257       &2.8152     &159.1169\\ 
10&ILE 61@O           &ARG 63@H       &ARG 63@N     &2152       &0.0218        &2.8859     &143.7632\\ 
11&ASN 64@O          &ARG 63@HH11     &ARG 63@NH1     &1379       &0.0139      &2.8298     &150.0209\\ 
12&ARG 63@O           &THR 65@HG1     &THR 65@OG1      &407       &0.0041      &2.8648     &161.4651\\ 
13&ASN 64@O            &ARG 63@HE      &ARG 63@NE      &325       &0.0033      &2.8589     &153.9301\\ 
14&ASN 64@O          &ARG 63@HH21     &ARG 63@NH2      &255       &0.0026      &2.8406     &148.6241\\ 
15&ARG 63@O             &THR 65@H       &THR 65@N      &255       &0.0026       &2.8795     &142.8652\\ 
16&ILE 61@O            &ARG 63@HE      &ARG 63@NE      &186       &0.0019       &2.8647     &156.4760\\ 
17&ASP 58@O             &ARG 63@H       &ARG 63@N      &163       &0.0016       &2.9154     &142.9759\\ 
18&THR 70@OG1        &ARG 63@HH22     &ARG 63@NH2       &88       &0.0009       &2.8805     &150.7732\\ 
19&ILE 61@O          &ARG 63@HH21     &ARG 63@NH2       &44       &0.0004       &2.8353     &147.7332\\ 
20&ASP 72@OD2        &ARG 63@HH12     &ARG 63@NH1       &25       &0.0003       &2.8411     &157.9767\\ 
21&THR 70@OG1        &ARG 63@HH12     &ARG 63@NH1       &25       &0.0003       &2.8827     &153.7517\\ 
22&VAL 68@O          &ARG 63@HH22     &ARG 63@NH2       &21       &0.0002       &2.9116     &150.5463\\ 
23&THR 70@OG1        &ARG 63@HH21     &ARG 63@NH2       &13       &0.0001       &2.8729     &148.6454\\ 
 24&ASP 72@OD2        &ARG 63@HH22     &ARG 63@NH2        &3       &0.0000       &2.9242     &143.7173\\ 
 25&ASP 58@OD2           &ARG 63@H       &ARG 63@N        &1       &0.0000       &2.9051     &137.9706\\ 
 26&GLY 62@O            &ARG 63@HE      &ARG 63@NE        &1       &0.0000       &2.9086     &161.4056\\ 
 27&ASP 72@OD1        &ARG 63@HH21     &ARG 63@NH2        &1       &0.0000       &2.9765     &139.9365\\
   \hline
 \end{longtable}
  \end{center}
```

Comment: `\begin{longtable}{|*8|}` is wrong -- to start with

Comment: {|*8|} is missing the column specification, also do not put longtable in a center environment and don't use `\bf` in late.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I am still wondering about *your* deep insight into `longtable* package ;-)

Comment: Perhaps the Amino acids could be displayed differently, to reduce the width of the table as well

Answer (score 2):

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{array,longtable}

\newcommand\hd[2]{\multicolumn{1}{#1}{\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}#2\end{tabular}}}

\begin{document}

\section{zzz}
X\dotfill X

{\footnotesize
\setlength\tabcolsep{2pt}
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
\begin{longtable}{@{}|*8{r}|@{}}
 \hline
\hd{@{}|c}{text}& 
\hd{c}{Acceptor}&
\hd{c}{Hydrogen\\atom}&
\hd{c}{Donor}&
\hd{c}{No. of\\Frames}&
\hd{c}{Fraction}&
\hd{c}{ Average\\Length}&
\hd{c|@{}}{Average\\Angle}\\
 \hline
1&GLU 73@OE2       & ARG 63@HH12     &ARG 63@NH1    &38472       &0.3890            &2.7931     &163.2221 \\
2&GLU 73@OE1        &ARG 63@HH22     &ARG 63@NH2    &35928       &0.3633       &2.7983     &162.5048 \\
3&ILE 61@O          &ARG 63@HH11     &ARG 63@NH1    &14490       &0.1465       &2.8612     &158.4143 \\
4&GLU 73@OE1        &ARG 63@HH21     &ARG 63@NH2    &14175       &0.1433       &2.7989     &158.1555\\ 
5&GLU 73@OE2         &ARG 63@HE      &ARG 63@NE     &8830       &0.0893        &2.8070     &158.1456\\ 
6&GLU 73@OE2        &ARG 63@HH22     &ARG 63@NH2     &6240       &0.0631       &2.8255     &153.4609\\
7&GLU 73@OE2        &ARG 63@HH21     &ARG 63@NH2     &3949       &0.0399       &2.8370     &150.3891\\
8&GLU 73@OE1         & ARG 63@HE      &ARG 63@NE     &2677       &0.0271       &2.8550     &150.1653\\
9&GLU 73@OE1        &ARG 63@HH12     &ARG 63@NH1     &2539       &0.0257       &2.8152     &159.1169\\ 
10&ILE 61@O           &ARG 63@H       &ARG 63@N     &2152       &0.0218        &2.8859     &143.7632\\ 
11&ASN 64@O          &ARG 63@HH11     &ARG 63@NH1     &1379       &0.0139      &2.8298     &150.0209\\ 
12&ARG 63@O           &THR 65@HG1     &THR 65@OG1      &407       &0.0041      &2.8648     &161.4651\\ 
13&ASN 64@O            &ARG 63@HE      &ARG 63@NE      &325       &0.0033      &2.8589     &153.9301\\ 
14&ASN 64@O          &ARG 63@HH21     &ARG 63@NH2      &255       &0.0026      &2.8406     &148.6241\\ 
15&ARG 63@O             &THR 65@H       &THR 65@N      &255       &0.0026       &2.8795     &142.8652\\ 
16&ILE 61@O            &ARG 63@HE      &ARG 63@NE      &186       &0.0019       &2.8647     &156.4760\\ 
17&ASP 58@O             &ARG 63@H       &ARG 63@N      &163       &0.0016       &2.9154     &142.9759\\ 
18&THR 70@OG1        &ARG 63@HH22     &ARG 63@NH2       &88       &0.0009       &2.8805     &150.7732\\ 
19&ILE 61@O          &ARG 63@HH21     &ARG 63@NH2       &44       &0.0004       &2.8353     &147.7332\\ 
20&ASP 72@OD2        &ARG 63@HH12     &ARG 63@NH1       &25       &0.0003       &2.8411     &157.9767\\ 
21&THR 70@OG1        &ARG 63@HH12     &ARG 63@NH1       &25       &0.0003       &2.8827     &153.7517\\ 
22&VAL 68@O          &ARG 63@HH22     &ARG 63@NH2       &21       &0.0002       &2.9116     &150.5463\\ 
23&THR 70@OG1        &ARG 63@HH21     &ARG 63@NH2       &13       &0.0001       &2.8729     &148.6454\\ 
 24&ASP 72@OD2        &ARG 63@HH22     &ARG 63@NH2        &3       &0.0000       &2.9242     &143.7173\\ 
 25&ASP 58@OD2           &ARG 63@H       &ARG 63@N        &1       &0.0000       &2.9051     &137.9706\\ 
 26&GLY 62@O            &ARG 63@HE      &ARG 63@NE        &1       &0.0000       &2.9086     &161.4056\\ 
 27&ASP 72@OD1        &ARG 63@HH21     &ARG 63@NH2        &1       &0.0000       &2.9765     &139.9365\\
   \hline
 \end{longtable}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much !
I tried it, it compiles successfully !
However I have 2pt above the table. 
The one of \setlength\extrarowheight{2pt} 
when I tried to remove it, the file did not compile.

Comment: @Hadeer If it didn't compile you made an error but unless you show what you did, and state what error message you got, then hard to help.